# SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18 with Web Workers

Tags: javascript, asset-pipeline, web-worker

I was getting an error SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18 when I deployed to my production server.

I narrowed it down to the Web Worker request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due the deployment process pushing the worker script out to a cdn causing the worker to be on a different domain.

This was fixed by placing the worker on the local server as to avoid a cross domain request

Comment: So if I were needing to use a worker as a service from a CDN, how would this be done -- with CORS maybe?

Rather, what I'm concerned with is:
How might I be able to use a worker from the local filesystem?

I am helping UCLA develop a technology which embodies a fractal-system of distributed-networking. So I have a SharedWorkers API which I need to be resourced across domains; each tab on one domain can access the SharedWorker no problem, but I need a 'GlobalWorker', if you will, so having the API call on the "GlobalWorker" is desirable. Everything needs to be at the Browser layer.